# IE7 - NoSuchElementException with Selenium

Tags: java, internet-explorer, xpath, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium on IE7 with [InternetExplorerDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) on Windows XP. This code works fine with Firefox, IE9 and even IE9 in compatibility mode (on W7).

HTML:

```
<HTML xml:lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="login">chicken</div>
</BODY>
```

Building driver:

```
private static WebDriver getIE7WebDriver() {
    WebDriver driver = null;
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
    capabilities= DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, false);
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS,true);
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS,true);
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "internet explorer");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "WINDOWS");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "7");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",(new File("C:\\selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe")).getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return driver;
}
```

And trying to get my `#index` element:

```
log.info(driver.getPageSource());

try {
    String value = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login")).toString();
    log.info(value);
}
catch ( Exception e ) {
    log.error(e.toString());
}
```

Page source is fetch properly, but anytime I try to access an element, I get a `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`. I also tried by `id` and `XPath`.

Any idea of what's going wrong ?

PS: In Windows XP, there is no security mode for IE.

EDIT: `driver.getPageSource()` returns:

```
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr"><HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV id=login>chicken</DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: What comes out when, under ie7, you tell selenium to print the page source?

Comment: Do you really need the IE7 and WinXP? I think both are **out of extended support** in April 2014.

Comment: @acdcjunior It prints exactly the HTML code I give in my question, except that `div` is uppercase.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach Unfortunatly, it's beyond my control, but yes I do (not WinXP but IE7 though).

Comment: What happens if you use a `WebDriverWait` to wait for the element?

Comment: @JimEvans: Same problem. `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for presence of element`

Comment: just for our clarification:  your intentions ARE to run against a hub, and the hub is on your local machine, correct?  You actually are running `java -jar selenium.jar -role hub`?

Comment: To add more info - I tested this on IE6 and with latest C# bindings and was able to replicate the issue. Running javascript `document.getElementById("login")` also failed with the same exception.

Comment: @sircapsalot I'm using the standalone server on a Windows VM with `java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\selenium\IE_driver_server\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.37.0.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - per the comments, you specified that you weren't running against the hub, yet, in your code - you point to a hub.  I think it has something to do with this.

Change this block of code:

```
try {
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to:

```
driver = new IEDriver(capabilities);
```

`RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")` this piece here is pointing your test to some remote driver, which means "a selenium node that is connected to a hub." You've already confirmed that this you are not using a hub, so this answer *should* solve your issue.

A breakdown:

```
RemoteWebDriver() = Selenium Node that is connected to a hub
ChromeDriver|IEDriver|FirefoxDriver = Local browser session
```

Comment: I assume you meant `new InternetExplorerDriver()`? It's far simplier this way (if I understand correctly I was connected to a local node), but it still doesn't solve the issue. But nevermind, I'll stick with IE9 in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

For IE 7 selenium server version 2.20 or below should given a try. Recently we face similar issue where few commands were working in IE 10 but not working in IE 8. When we downgrade upto selenium 2.20 (tried one by one) and it worked fine for IE 8 with 2.20. If you are using hub then make sure node running selenium server has older vesion (<2.20) of selenium running.